# Wordpress Plugin Shortcode Disturbs Page Content Put Alongwith it into the Editor

Tags: wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I have created a plugin with short code now when I access the plugin through short code it works fine issue is that when I put some text above the short code that text goes below the plugin when i view the page.

Here is code that I put into wordpress editor:

```
    <p>Unlock your device safely in 3 steps</p>

    [CUSTOMSLIDER]
```

you can see the plugin shortcode is on second row but static text is on first row but when I will view the page the text goes below the plugin. [here you can see](http://www.loaded24.de/?page_id=4) its view.  you can see the slider is at top and the text is below slider though these were opposite in original source.

Comment: I create my own plugin for slider

Comment: you can see the code of plugin by viewing source of page http://www.loaded24.de/?page_id=4

Answer (score 0):

in your custom plugin, instead of:

echo "content";

change that to:

$variable .= "content";

return $variable

from:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/shortcode-moving-to-top-of-entry-content